# Firebase local notification in background in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to implement local Firebase notifications in background in Android with Flutter.

Following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages) tutorial, I was able to get my notifications successfully set up when the app is in foreground. But while the app is in background, I do see the local notifications, but also the original notifications sent by Firebase (which I do not see while the app is in foreground).

This is a problem. Since our server sends multiple notifications, and I am implementing android_local_notifications to filter through them, and show only selected ones though local notification channel.

This is my implementation:

```
void main() {
  // Register local notification channel
  static final AndroidNotificationChannel androidChannel =
      AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'android_local_notifications',
    'Android Local Notifications',
    description: 'Used to show foreground notifications on Android.',
    importance: Importance.max,
  );

  static final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: null),
    );


  // set up on background
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}


/// Handle background messages by registering a onBackgroundMessage handler.
/// When messages are received, an isolate is spawned (Android only, iOS/macOS does not require a separate isolate) allowing you to handle messages even when your application is not running.
/// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // Initialize firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Creates a local notification
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notificationHashCode,
      translatedTitleString,
      translatedBodyString,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          androidChannel.id,
          androidChannel.name,
          channelDescription: androidChannel.description,
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
                android:exported="true" tools:replace="android:exported"/>
```

How do I get to hide the original Firebase pushes while the app is in background?

Comment: working on the same problem too, is you flutter local notification showing when it's in onbackgroundmessage handler? mine doesn't and i would really appreciate any help.

Comment: onbackgroundmessage is not even getting triggered when the app isn't active.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the fcm channel to your local channel than you wont see the second notification

```html
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="your_channel_id" />
```

or you can try not to set notification element in your fcm request body

```html
{ "message":{ "token":"", "data":{ "title":"title", "body":"body" } } }
```